# How to finding webElement (on Facebook) using selenium using java

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, automated-tests

I'm create a test Script where i post on my wall in Facebook but I was unable to locate the element `(getting an NoSuchElementException)` even though the element exist and I was trying to find a `cssSelector` using FirePath.

[image]

I can't find any of the elements ('post', 'photo/video', and etc) or write on the wall. 
I have tried below mentioned code:

```
@Test
public void doTest(){
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("kryptonitecricket@gmail.com");
    WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
    element.sendKeys("windcore123");
    element.submit();
    doThread();

    WebElement element1;
     element1= driver.findElement(By.id("pagelet_composer"));
    element1.click();
    element1=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mainContainer>#contentCol"........);
    WebElement element2=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("._1mf7._4jy0._4jy3._4jy1._51sy.selected._42ft"));
    element2.click();
}
```

I am very new to selenium and testing
Thank you

Comment: First of your code will break every time Facebook changes the class names which is all the time. Secondly Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API

Comment: If it is not about Facebook then explain what problem you are having and which site you have problem with

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath instead of CSS, as we know it says  "What's on your mind" ; therefore we can use this to find the status:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@title=\"What's on your mind?\"]"))
```

i think this should work

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to identified an element by xpath.